# Merge Key constraint with Entityframework

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am a .NEt student trying to build a simple pizza webbshop. I am using Entityframework to build the database. The errormessage I get is this:

```
 The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_Categories_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "TomasosPizzeria", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have googled and tried to solve this pne alone by renaming the properties back and forth. Here are my classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string Ingridients { get; set; }

    //--

    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Categories")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
}




public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }
```

I am using a DbInitializer to set som test values. I have had problems giving the product object a category with the corresponding value.

```
 var categories = new Category[]
             {
                new Category{CategoryName="Pizza"},
                new Category{CategoryName="Pasta"},
                new Category{CategoryName="Sallad"},

             };


   var products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product{ProductName="Äcklig Calzone", Ingridients="Gamla tomater, möglig ost, trötta oliver, Unken skinka", ProductPrice=150},
        new Product{ProductName="Italiensk skit", Ingridients="Proscutti, halvfärdig mozzarella, trötta oliver, skämd vattnig proscutti", ProductPrice=250},
        new Product{ProductName="La bussola", Ingridients="Äckliga tomater, giftiga räkor, levande musslor, rutten skinka",CategoryID = 2,<--Here-- ProductPrice = 105 }


    };

    foreach (Product s in products)
    {
        context.Products.Add(s);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

I am thankful for all the help I get. Please tell me if you wish to see any more of my code.

Comment: First, what do you mean by *I am using a **DbInitializer***? Second, I don't see you using the `categories` variable. Third, the first two products have no `CategoryID` or `Categories` (btw, the name is strange, you should really use singular form) property, so they will also generate exception. Finally, how do you know the `CategoryID` 2 exists?

Comment: Hello, with DbInitializer I mean I have class called DbInitializer with a method in it called Initialize that populates the database with testdata upon creation. You are totally right, it should be in singular form. Changed it. Gave the first two products `CategoryID` and everything went well for now. Thank you for your asnwer. Another question, When do you thing I should use `public virtual User User { get; set; }` or `public User User { get; set; }` as navigational propertys. I havent really undestod the difference yet.

Comment: There is no difference in EF Core for now. The `virtual` keyword supported so called lazy loading in EF6, which is not implemented yet in Core, so eventually would make difference in some future version when they implement it (eventually).

Comment: Thank you for your time and knowledge!! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by giving CategoryID to the two other products.

Comment: when you have FK, and you use initializer as you did here, you need to assign that for each entity. i.e. here you create products, and you need to assign "CategoryID" to each one. as you pointed yourself. plus I feel your pain when EXPERTS here, don't have tolerance for juniors. but they try so hard to answer as much as they can and that's valuable, even if it doesn't help. good luck

Comment: I had the same issue a while back, What is wrong was, I was inserting a different `Id` to the foreign key field.